# How to set the correct PATH for different software

Tags: bash, path

I installed R via Conda. During the installation Terminal says `environment location: /Users/tymac/anaconda3...The following packages will be downloaded:...`.  Everything was installed but now at bash prompt: `computer:~ tymac$ R` `-bash: R: command not found`.

If I search manually I see that the R folder was installed in `/Users/tymac/anaconda3/lib/(R-folder)`. The R executable was installed in `/Users/tymac/anaconda3/bin/(R-executable)`. (printenv actually says that executable is RSTUDIO).

If I do *echo $PATH* I get
`/Users/tymac/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet`

Why are they installed in different locations and what is the best solution for these paths since Terminal is not recognizing R?

This is my `.bash_profile` when I installed Anaconda a while ago. I do not have a `.bashrc` file.

EDIT: just added this path for R. Can I remove all of the Anaconda script?

```
# added by me just now
export PATH=/Users/tymac/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false 

'/Users/tymac/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/tymac/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/tymac/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/tymac/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

# <<< conda init <<<
```

Comment: "Why are they installed in different locations"  could I ask what are you talking about? R, or the different locations in the PATH?

Comment: Hello. Yes, R specifically with the script that Anaconda installed, but I would like to know how to properly set up environment variables in macOS for future reference since I need to make sure I'm always using the most up to date versions etc. eg I don't know why I have two different R locations.

Comment: Actually I just added my own variable `export PATH=/Users/tymac/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` with vim.  And now I can get the R prompt. But I would like to know if I need to keep that script installed by Anaconda or should I remove it from .bash_profile? Then with future new Anaconda installations on new machines do I let Anaconda do its thing and then after remove the Anaconda script? And....why are there two install locations? i.e. the R executable at bin location and the R folder at lib location?

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I am on the right........ahem, "path". lol